# Which VESA mount do I need for an ASUS RT AC87U router?

Tags: router

So, it's way past time to mount [this router](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00MPI5N7U) to the wall. I looked on the back and there are some keyhole looking mounting holes in the back. However, they're too small (diameter and depth) for any kind of screw I've found (even *exotic* pancake-head screws).

I contacted ASUS support and they said, simply, that it's "VESA compatible". I searched on Amazon.com and found 10,000 results for "[VESA mount](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Delectronics&field-keywords=vesa+mount&rh=n%3A172282%2Ck%3Avesa+mount)".

I want to wall mount this with a little bit of room between the wall and the router to thread the network cable (so it's not running around the side or over the front of the unit).

I guess I need to figure out which VESA "size" it is? For example, this [flush wall mount](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007Y4TV14) supports 50, 75, and 100.

Am I on the right track?

---

Photo, for reference ([source](https://www.smallnetbuilder.com/wireless/wireless-reviews/32485-asus-rt-ac87u-dual-band-wireless-ac2400-gigabit-router-first-look)).

[image]

Comment: Did you try wood screws? They usually have a countersink head.

Comment: *"they're too small (diameter and depth) for any kind of screw I've found (even exotic pancake-head screws)"* -- I don't know what you've *"found"*, but there are many sizes of screws and types of screwheads.  IMO the answer you got from the ASUS tech is suspect.  AFAIK VESA mounting expects threaded bolt holes, not mounting slots, on the device to be mounted.